# Заменить символы фигур и доски в библиотеке python chess

Tags: python

Пишем с ребёнком простого бота на **Python** для шахмат в Discord с использованием библиотеки **chess**. Проблема в том, что доска адекватно выводится в IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но когда отправляем в Discord, выглядит иначе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Гипотеза**: в мессенджере не моноширинный шрифт, поэтому "вёрстка" ломается.

**Идея**: заменить символы-буквы на смайлики одинаковой ширины. Но читаю документацию, не нахожу возможности заменить символы.

```
board = chess.Board('rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1')
```

Возможно, у вас будут какие-то другие здравые решения, буду признателен.

Comment: Мне кажется надо всё-таки в сторону правильных шрифтов копать. Но больше не подскажу, не знаю как там шрифт выбрать.

Comment: Да, Markdown работает, но всё таки сложно ориентироваться по буквам вместо фигур. Особенно в процессе игры. ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙ ♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟

Comment: Вы ведь в мессенджер строку `str(board)` отправляете? Вот на этом шаге и делайте замену. Вопрос только в том, чем заменить пробел, так чтобы он имел туже ширину. Попробуйте "░▓"

Comment: Или отравлять как пре-форматированный текст (aka "Code Blocks") https://www.howtogeek.com/674569/how-to-apply-text-formatting-in-discord/